# Windows 10 Updates: Win 10 updates its version in increasing order (going through each update)?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, operating-systems, storage, windows-installation

I had installed window 10 (genuine and it was some oldest version of win 10)on my laptop in drive with 50 GB storage, since win 10 has been upgraded every twice (approximately) a year, so every update takes a bit of storage and up until now it has upgraded to latest version 1709 (haven't gone to 1803 yet as I stopped it), and it has taken almost 40 GB of my storage.

My question is this: if I install again win 10 (the old version I had), and it starts updating itself, will it be updated directly to the latest version or won't update at all or would update going through each version just like it did before?

Plus...Even if it updates directly to latest version say 1803, then would it take same storage as it did update every version over the years.?

Comment: It probably takes 40 GB because of the Windows.old folder. Have you tried disk cleanup?

Comment: Yes..it saved me about 2 and half GB..

Comment: The previous version of Windows is removed shortly after you upgrade.  If your system partition is Dillon up it isn’t from installing feature updates

Comment: Try running WizTree to see what's using all your space.